# I cannot get Eclipse MinGW and Sqlite to Work Together for a C program

Tags: c, eclipse, sqlite, mingw

So I have spent the whole day trying to figure this out, and alas I have failed.  I need help!  So I installed Eclipse and MinGW so that I can write a C program.  I am new to all of this.  I need to be able to access an sqlite database.  So I downloaded the sqlite amalgamation and unzipped it to C:/sqlite3 and it contains two .c files and two .h files.  In the examples, I have seen online they include the sqlite.h header file as follows:

```c
#include <sqlite.h>
```

So I think that I need to add an includes folder holding my sqlite info. So I click on my project and select Properties>C/C++ General>Paths and Symbols.  With the "Includes" tab selected and the Language GNU C highlighted, I add the Include directory C:\sqlite3.  So far no problems, I can build a project that prints my name in the console.

Now I add some sample code from a tutorial site:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I get 3 errors claiming undefined reference to the sqlite3 functions. So I think I need to add a link to sqlite3 in the compiler. So now I go to Properties>C/C++ Build/Settings and add -lsqlite3 to the MinGW C Linker Command line. Now my errors disappear when I build the project, but I get a compile error that says this:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3
```

It looks like it is looking for the sqlite3 files in the MinGW directories.  I am stuck.  I have tried pasting the file in the MinGW directory and even that doesn't work.  I know that I am missing something obvious to the world, but I only have about 5 pieces of hair left on my head and could really use some insight.  Please help me to get Eclipse set up using MinGW and accessing Sqlite. Thanks!

Comment: `-lsqlite3` would be if you link by calling your compiler ( ie: gcc, clang, etc ...), while linking with `ld` you would use `-l sqlite3 -L <searchdir for the static lib>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amalgamation is supposed to be compiled together with your other source files. Just add the `.c` file to your project, as if it were one of your own source files.

Comment: I added the sqlite.c and sqlite.h to my src folder as you suggested.  I got rid of the paths to the sqlite3 folder I mentioned earlier.  I left in the -lsqlite3 command in the MinGW linker.  I have 3 problems still.  There is a warning triangle on my sqlite3.c file in the src folder.  The line #include <sqlite3.h> says fatal error: sqlite3.h no such file or directory. And during build, it says ..\src\RealDealProcessor.c:12:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Drop the `-lsqlite3`. You need to add the directory of the .h file to the include path.

Comment: You are the man!  I think that we got it working.  It built, no errors, and ran as expected. The only problem is that there is still a little warning triangle on the sqlite3.c folder and I have no idea why.  Do you know how I can find out.

Comment: I don't know how seriously to take this warning, but this is what it says down in the Problems view: variable 'bRc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable] sqlite3.c /RealDealProcessor/src line 26579 C/C++ Problem